# Jasmine test for Angular can't find my controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I'm having trouble setting up Jasmine tests for an Angular app. Jasmine can't find my controller (I suspect it can't find my app at all).

Here is a sample that demonstrates the problem I'm running into:

```
angular.module('testMod', [])
    .controller('testController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.person = {name: 'Jim', age: 14};

        function innerFunction() {}

    }]);
```

Test:

```
  describe('testMod suite', function() {

        var $rootScope, myController;

        beforeEach( inject(function($injector) {
            angular.module('testMod');

            $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
            var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');
            myController = $controller('testController', {$scope: $rootScope});

        }) );

    it('works', function() {
        expect( typeof myController.innerFunction).toBe('function');
    });
});
```

It fails on the line

```
myController = $controller('testController', {$scope: $rootScope});
```

The error I'm seeing is:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'testController' is not a function, got undefined
```

I'm using the standalone SpecRunner.html for Jasmine, with my app and spec loaded:

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Jasmine Spec Runner v2.0.0</title>

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine_favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/boot.js"></script>
  <!-- angular-mock must be loaded AFTER Jasmine -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../src/angular-1.2.5.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../src/angular-mock-1.2.5.js"></script>

    <!-- include source files here... -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../src/testMod.js"></script>

  <!-- include spec files here... -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="spec/testMod.Test.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions are appreciated - I've been struggling with this for a while now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your test:

1. You are not injecting scope properly.
2. You are not using scope properly.
3. There is a toBeDefined() method to check if function is defined no need to type check.

Change the code in your test to

```
describe('testMod suite', function() {

var $rootScope, testController;

beforeEach(module('testMod'));
beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
    myScope = $rootScope.$new();
    ctrl = $controller('testController', {
        $scope: myScope
    });
}));

it('works', function() {
    expect( myScope.innerFunction).toBeDefined();
});
});
```

Also, change your angular controller code to:

```
angular.module('testMod', [])
.controller('testController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.person = {name: 'Jim', age: 14};

    $scope.innerFunction = function() {}

}]);
```